# How to write response to file using php

Tags: php

I wish to write the response of hitting a given url into the href attribute of an anchor tag using PHP. How can I do this?

Here's an example of what I excpect to happen

```
mylink.com/getdoc?name=documentA
```

returns a string as a response:

```
mylink.com/document2012-03-15.pdf
```

I need to write this response (using PHP into the href attribute as shown below:

```
<a href="mylink.com/document2012-03-15.pdf"> Open Document A </a>
```

(so the above will be the final source of my page.

Comment: What part exactly is the problem here? Getting the contents of a URL, displaying a link, ...?

Comment: How can I make it clearer? - I have asked "I wish to write the response of hitting a given url into the href attribute" and given a demo of what I expect to happen

Comment: Yeah you did, but what is the problem? What part can't you figure out? Have you tried anything?

Comment: how can I write the response from hitting a url into the href attribute using php. I am still asking the same question but just re-arranging the words. I cannot ask a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a few ways to do what you want. Not all of them will work exactly as you ask for, but the end result should be the same.

#### Solution one

My first possible solution was already posted by @shanethehat. You could use `file_get_contents` to call your PHP script via HTTP and get the response.

#### Solution two

Another possible solution was suggested in the comments of the post by @YourCommonSense. You could simply `include` the `getdoc` script in the PHP script that is generating your HTML file, like this:

```
$_GET["name"] = "documentA";
echo "<a href=\"". include("getdoc.php") ."\"> Open Document A </a>";
```

#### Solution three

Or you could change the way the `getdoc` script works. You could use a script more like this:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=\"{$_GET["name"]}\"");
readfile($_GET["name"]);
```

And you keep your link like this: `<a href="mylink.com/getdoc.php?name=documentA"> Open Document A </a>`. When `getdoc.php` is called, it will get the specified file and start a file download.

**NOTE:** you should probably do some input sanitization with this method (removing slashes, making sure the file ends in .pdf, etc) to make sure someone doesn't try to get a file they're not allowed to get.

That's all I'm coming up with at the moment. There might be a more clever way to do it, but hopefully one of these solutions will do it for you. I would try solution 2 or 3 first, and if they don't work out for you, then go with solution 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    //get output from URL
    $myfile = file_get_contents('http://mylink.com/getdoc?name=documentA');
?>
<a href="<?php echo $myfile; ?>">Open Document A</a>
```

Comment: Don't want to be snarky but ... thanks for supporting laziness and bad questions :/

Comment: @JanHančič No worries, the answer missed the question by a mile anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise I'd misunderstood.  It seemed like the OP wanted to be able to retrieve filenames from a different script and embed them in his HTML.  If that was the case then I don't see anything wrong with showing that `file_get_contents()` can be used in that way.

Comment: @shanethehat that's how I understand the question too. My point was that OP did a very poor job communicating his problem and shouldn't be rewarded until he clarifies and improves his question. We shouldn't have to be force to decypher what OPs want.

Comment: @Jan - I (thought that I) had no trouble understanding the question, but it just sturck me as someone who might not speak good English.

Comment: @JanHančič: I don't think the answer was *that* unclear and I think this solution would work for the OP. Granted, it may not be the best way to do it, but still, it would probably do what the OP wants. And BTW, you should read this - [When should I vote down?](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: @JanHančič I am not lazy. I am new to PHP, and am sorry I have not explained myself clearly enough. I have now updated and it is hopefully more clearer.

Comment: @Travesty3 I didn't downvote ;) And I wasn't saying that the solution is bad. I was just arguing that the OP did not deserve to receive it.

Comment: Thanks, This looks like what I may need. I will test it now.

Comment: @Travesty3 - I'm here to learn too, if there's a better technique for this then I need to learn it :)

Comment: I will post an answer indicating some other possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> How to write response to file using php

Noway.
PHP do not process HTTP requests.
You have to set up your web server to do the rewrite.
There are 100500 questions under mod_rewrite tag, you will find the solution easily.

Note that you may wish to rewrite your url to `/getdoc.php?name=document2012-03-15.pdf`, not one you mentioned in your question

Comment: I don't think you quite understood the question. The /getdoc returns a string not the whole file. At least that's how I understood it.

Comment: Yes. the getdoc returns a string with the path to the latest document. Whose name changes and thus I cannot link directly to it.

Comment: @MarkW why do you call getdoc via HTTP, why don't you include the code and get the variable returned from it?

Comment: because I didnt write it and it requires an value on the querystring. But good suggestion

Comment: @MarkW: What if you did something like `$_GET["name"] = "documentA"; echo "<a href=\"". include("getdoc.php") ."\"> Open Document A </a>";`?